# Почему я не могу получить тип элемента вектора, передаваемого по универсальной ссылке? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных

Есть такой код:

```
template<typename Container>
void foo(Container&& c) {
    
    std::cout << typeid(Container::value_type).name() << "\n";

}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку, что Container - это не класс. Сделал так:

```
std::cout << typeid(Container).name() << "\n";
```

В консоль вывелось class std::vector<int,class std::allocator>, разве это не значит, что Container - это все таки класс вектора? Почему тогда я не могу получить доступ к value_type?

Comment: В таких случаях следует использовать `::std::remove_reference`, а для проверки типа - `::std::is_same`

Comment: достаточно вот так написать `std::cout << typeid(typename Container::value_type).name() << "\n";` и gcc/clang уже могут.

Comment: @KoVadim ну VS не проглатывает)

Comment: попробовал в 2017 студии - сразу смогло. в 2019 ругалось на шаблон, но добавка /EHcs сразу сняла все вопросы. И выводит int

Comment: @KoVadim Вот что бывает, когда люди игнорируют необходимость приводить [mcve].

Comment: как по мне, то в вопросе достаточно "минимальный воспроизводимый пример". правда только у автора

Comment: @KoVadim если не сложно, то почему добавка решает проблему? Из-за чего вполне логичный код не хочет компилироваться без добавки?

Comment: Почитайте о двухфазной компиляции шаблонов. Если кратко, то компилятору не очевидно, что там шаблон. А typename намекает компилятору об этом

Comment: @KoVadim да, я знаю про typename, но в том-то и вопрос, почему typename не работает?)

Comment: видимо, Вам нужно показать полный пример. у меня все компилируется.

Comment: @KoVadim залил примерный обрезок на https://godbolt.org/z/cxeYqeYPz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас Container это не просто тип, а `std::vector<int>&` (или другие подобные).  Поэтому, удалим ссылочность. Это можно сделать двумя способами

```
std::cout << typeid(typename std::decay<Container>::type::value_type).name() << "\n";
```

или

```
std::cout << typeid(typename std::remove_reference<Container>::type::value_type).name() << "\n";
```

то есть, удаляем тип не у `Container::value_type`, а вначале снимаем ссылку с `Container`, а потом у него уже берем вложенный тип.